# How to add a popup on Ratings? [Semantic-UI]

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I have a Rating System on my site and i want to add a popup (popover for bootstraper's) on the stars!

```
 <div id="rating" class="ui massive star rating" data-rating="0" data-max-rating="5"></div>
```

Some alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not available in Semantic-UI for the moment , but you can achieve it by doing the following :

[[Working DEMO]](https://codepen.io/SaadRegal/pen/yoejgV?editors=1010)

1- Initialize your rating module and add settings to it :

```
$('.ui.rating')
  .rating({
    maxRating: 5,
  })
;
```

2- Create an array that will contains rating text for each star :

```
var rate= ['hate it','bad','just ok','like it','love it'];
```

3- Add that text for each start in `data-ratetext` attribute

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.each($('#rating > i.icon'), function (index, item) {
        $(item).attr('data-ratetext', rate[index]);
    });
})
```

4- Initialize popups for each star with the text taken for `data-ratetext` attribute:

```
 $(document).on('mouseenter', '#rating > i.icon', function() {
    $(this)
       .popup({
           title: $(this).attr('data-ratetext'),
            on:'hover'
       })
       .popup('show');
});
```

Comment: one little problem, i have another icons on my page, and they are popup the rate. i can change this to a class or id that only rate can have?

Comment: change  `'i.icon'` selector  to  `'#rating > i.icon'`